# Angular 5 - Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'

Tags: angular

`Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'`

I'm facing this issue after run this command.`npm install angular-loader`

Comment: Isn't `angular-loader` an `AngularJS` lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you tried to install a module for AngularJS:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-loader

please run following command to solve your issue:

```
npm uninstall angular-loader -S -D -O
```

Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall